# Grunt - Task doesn't support multitask?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have this `image_resize` task that I run on one set of files, but I want to run it again on another set of files. I've tried the following:

```
image_resize: {
  task1: {
    options: {
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      overwrite: true
    },
    files: {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'some cwd',
      src: ['*.png'],
      dest: 'some dest'
    }
  },
  task2: {
    options: {
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      overwrite: true
    },
    files: {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'some cwd',
      src: ['*.png'],
      dest: 'some dest'
    }
  }
},
```

But I get the error: `Warning: Object true has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.`

Is there no way to do it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [grunt-image-resize](https://github.com/excellenteasy/grunt-image-resize) then please change to the `files:` so that they are arrays of objects instead of single objects. Doing so will put them into [files array format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format).

```
image_resize: {
  task1: {
    options: {
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      overwrite: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'some cwd',
      src: ['*.png'],
      dest: 'some dest'
    }]
  },
  task2: {
    options: {
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      overwrite: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'some cwd',
      src: ['*.png'],
      dest: 'some dest'
    }]
  }
},
```

Comment: What if I wanted different width/heights for each set of files?

Comment: This should be able to do a separate sizing for each task.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the brackets around files. This worked, thanks.